# Blender 2.8 different worlds settings for different view layers

Tags: rendering, world, viewlayers

Is it possible to have 2 different worlds in Blender 2.8? If positive, how do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible by using a new view layer, however you can create a new scene which has it's own world settings.

Comment: rjg, thank you for your prompt reply. I will do exactly that. Cheers.